# Numpy array from YAML

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, yaml

I have a configuration file in YAML which contains strings, floats, integers and a list. I would like, when the YAML is loaded to return the list a numpy array. So, for example, if the YAML is as follows:

```
name: 'John Doe'
age: 20
score:
  -- 19
   - 45
  -- 21
   - 12
  -- 32
   - 13
```

and I read this by

```
import yaml

def read(CONFIG_FILE):
    with open(CONFIG_FILE) as c:
        return yaml.load(c)

config = read('path\to\yml')
```

then I would like `config['score']` instead of list to be typed as a `numpy.array`. Of course, this could easily be done outside YAML with something like `numpy.array(config['score'])` but I want to avoid that.

I have tried setting the tag as described in the documentation (https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation) but I can not make it work. So for example, the following fails:

```
score:!!python/object:numpy.array
  -- 19
   - 45
  -- 21
   - 12
  -- 32
   - 13
```

Changing the tag to   `!!python/module:numpy.array` or `!!python/name:numpy.array` doesn't work either.

How can I make this work? I am using Python v.3

Comment: There is no list (i.e. sequence in your YAML), because there are no spaces after the dash that starts the value for `score`, that is not sequence entry indicator and that and the rest is one plain multi-line scalar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dumping a numpy array with the data that you get, will get you a
vastly more complex YAML file than what you can get by just adding a
tag. I therefore recommend that you just define a tag of your own that
causess the data as you have it to load, and then convert to numpy on
the fly. That way you don't have to walk over the resulting loaded structure to find `score` or its value.

`config.yaml`:

```
name: 'John Doe'
age: 20
score: !2darray
  -- 19
   - 45
  -- 21
   - 12
  -- 32
   - 13
```

You also have to realize that the value for `score` in that file is a plain multi-line
scalar, that will get loaded as the string `'-- 19 - 45 -- 21 - 12 -- 32 - 13'`

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml
from pathlib import Path
import numpy

config_file = Path('config.yaml')

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')

@yaml.register_class
class Array:
    yaml_tag = '!2darray'

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        array = []
        for x in node.value.split():
            if x == '--':
                sub_array = []
                array.append(sub_array)
                continue
            if x == '-':
                continue
            sub_array.append(int(x))
        return numpy.array(array)

data = yaml.load(config_file)
print(type(data['score']))
print(data)
```

which gives:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
{'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 20, 'score': array([[19, 45],
       [21, 12],
       [32, 13]])}
```

If in your input the value for `score` would be sequence of sequences,
which requires a **space** after the `-`, that only then gets interpreted as
a sequence entry indicator:

```
name: 'John Doe'
age: 20
score: !2darray
  - - 19
    - 45
  - - 21
    - 12
  - - 32
    - 13
```

If that would be the input, then you need to adapt the `from_yaml` method:

```
@yaml.register_class
class Array:
    yaml_tag = '!2darray'

    @classmethod
    def from_yaml(cls, constructor, node):
        array = constructor.construct_sequence(node, deep=True)
        return numpy.array(array)
```

Which gives exactly the same output as before.

Comment: That should be "Its yaml.load()".

Comment: you are correct, and the statement was outdated las PyYAML finally got updated to not default to unsafe behaviour